# Optimize Swift function to find a specific set of combinations of 3 digits within a larger integer array

Tags: arrays, swift, combinations

I'm working on a function that will help me quickly find all the upper structure triads (3-note chord) that I can add to a 4-note 7th chord to create a larger compound chord, as well of the roots and names of each triad. The example I'm testing right now is a 13#11 chord, which has the following degrees in a 12-note octave (when the root is 0): `[0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10]`*

*side note: `[0, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10]` would also match as a 13#11.

The base 7th chord is a dominant 7th: `[0, 4, 7, 9]`.I already know which triads complete the chord: a major triad on the 9th, `[2, 6, 9]`, and a diminished triad on the #11, `0, 6, 9` (only the `6` (#11th) and `9` (13th) are actually necessary to build a 13#11 chord; the `2` (9th) is optional).

I actually already have a function that will give me these results, I'm just wondering if there's a faster/more efficient way to do it? It just feels a little bulky/clunky right now. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Jake

```
extension Int {
    func degreeInOctave() -> Int {
        switch self {
        case 0...11:
            return self
        case 12...:
            return self - 12
        default:
            return self + 12
        }
    }
}

var ust: [Int] = [0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10]

let maj = [0, 4, 7]
let min = [0, 3, 7]
let aug = [0, 4, 8]
let dim = [0, 3, 6]
let sus4 = [0, 5, 7]
let sus2 = [0, 2, 7]
let triadDegs = [maj, min, aug, dim, sus4, sus2]

var triadRoots: [Int] = []
var triadQualities: [String] = []

func findUpperStructureTriads(degs: [Int]) {
    let degCount = degs.count

    var firstIndex = 0

    while firstIndex < (degCount - 2) {
        var secondIndex = firstIndex + 1

        while secondIndex < (degCount - 1) {
            var thirdIndex = secondIndex + 1

            while thirdIndex < (degCount) {
                var threeNoteGroup = [degs[firstIndex], degs[secondIndex], degs[thirdIndex]]

                func checkForTriad(triad: [Int]) -> Bool {
                    if triadDegs.contains(triad) {
                        switch triad {
                        case maj:
                            triadQualities.append("major")
                        case min:
                            triadQualities.append("minor")
                        case aug:
                            triadQualities.append("augmented")
                        case dim:
                            triadQualities.append("diminished")
                        case sus4:
                            triadQualities.append("sus4")
                        case sus2:
                            triadQualities.append("sus2")
                        default:
                            ()
                        }
                        return true
                    } else {
                        return false
                    }
                }
                if threeNoteGroup.contains(6), threeNoteGroup.contains(9){
                    var inversionCount = 0
                    var newGroup = threeNoteGroup.map {$0 - threeNoteGroup[0]}

                    while inversionCount < 3 {

                        func invert() {
                            newGroup = newGroup.map {($0 - newGroup[1]).degreeInOctave()}
                            let newlast = newGroup.remove(at: 0)
                            newGroup.append(newlast)
                        }
                        if checkForTriad(triad: newGroup) {
                            print(threeNoteGroup, threeNoteGroup[inversionCount])
                            triadRoots.append(threeNoteGroup[inversionCount])
                            break
                        }
                        invert()
                        inversionCount += 1
                    }
                }
                thirdIndex += 1
            }
            secondIndex += 1
        }
        firstIndex += 1
    }

    for i in 0...(triadRoots.count - 1) {
        print(triadRoots[i], triadQualities[i])
    }
}

findUpperStructureTriads(degs: ust)
```

outputs:

```
[0, 6, 9] 6
[2, 6, 9] 2
6 diminished
2 major
```

Comment: Maybe this question would be more suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swift)

Comment: I agree this is fairly clunky. The main reason is that you're treating notes as Int and triads as [Int] and qualities as Strings. But that isn't what they are. It's not sensible to call `quality.prefix(2)` or anything like that; it's not "a string of characters." To improve this code, you'll want to extract types that represent the things you're interested in discussing. Then, for example, you would have a (possibly computed) property like `triad.quality` (which would return an enum).

Comment: Thanks @ielyamani, I didn't know about Code Review. I'll check it out and likely post this there.

Comment: Thanks @RobNapier, can you elaborate a bit please? I'm familiar with enums (actually spent the past 2 weeks or so reworking the rest of my code to use them) but I'm a little unclear as to how they would help here. Actually, I can definitely see how they would help with the qualities array. But why wouldn't Int and [Int] make sense for the combinations (and what would Enums improve)? I guess I'm also wondering, since I'm just looking at numbers to build the triads (disregarding enharmonic spelling—like I don't care if I'm adding F# or Gb to my C7 chord), why not use Ints to represent notes?

Comment: By note I don't mean F#. I mean "offset 2 from the root." The fact that you added `degreeInOctave` to Int indicates that "notes" (or offsets?) have properties that are not universal to integers. The struct may just be `struct Note { let offset: Int }` (and maybe "note" is the wrong word here; semitone?), but that gives you something to put methods on. Similarly a Triad is not "any number of notes" (like [Int]). It has a requirements, and you enforce those in `init`.

Comment: That makes sense. So in terms of describing my objects (notes and triads), I want to find a way to structure them so that they can only have the values they're supposed to have (e.g. 0-11 for notes rather than any Int if I want to keep them within an octave; only three notes per triad object rather than any number of Ints in an [Int])? I can see how that would reduce the clunkiness. I do think that's a good idea. I'm just having a bit of trouble envisioning what restructuring my objects would do to make iterating through the combinations less clunky. Or is that part of the code OK already?